# List of class types unclarity

Tags: java, list, generics

Is something like this possible? i cant get it to work:

```
class B extends A {
...
}

class A {
...
}

List<Class<? extends A>> list(){
 return Arrays.asList(B.class);
}
```

I get `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Class<B>> to List<Class<? extends A>>.`

Comment: "I get some generics compilation error" *what* error? Always post the exact error message.

Comment: Note this compiles in Java 8, which has "improved type inference".

Comment: @James, do you know if there's a way to do this in Java 7?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, it compiles fine for Java 8 (enhanced *target typing*). In older versions, you have to do this:

```
List<Class<? extends A>> list() {
    return Arrays.<Class<? extends A>>asList(B.class);
}
```

Further reading:

- [Java Programming Language Enhancements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/enhancements.html)
- [Type Inference (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Generics (Updated))](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)